# .htaccess rewrite URL for multiple pages and fetch arguments passed to the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess code which works as expected which is

```
 http://example.com/profile.php
```

to

```
 http://example.com/someprofile
```

But I'm passing arguments in the URL such as,

```
 http://example.com/profile.php?username=someprofile
```

I need the above to be changed to the following,

```
 http://example.com/someprofile
```

I also need to fetch the argument 'someprofile' in PHP using $_GET['username']. I'm exhausted of chances..

Comment: what does the section of your .htaccess file that you wrote to try and handle this currently look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /profile\.php\?username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i removed the '/' before profile and now it works. But how will i fetch the argument 'username' in PHP ?

Comment: In the php page use `$username = $_GET["username"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
http://example.com/profile.php?username=([a-z]*)
```

then you can redirect to

```
http://example.com/$1
```

I'm not sure if it is $1 or \1 but you have to use regular expression